# How to add delete icon to appended images

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2

I append images to my div with this code:

```
$(function() {

var imagesPreview = function(input, placetoinsert) {

    if (input.files) {
        var filesAmount = input.files.length;

        for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            if (i>=5) {
                break;
            }
            reader.onload = function(event) {
                $($.parseHTML('<img>')).attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo('.preview').addClass('added_images');

            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
        }
    }
};

$('#gallery-photo-add').on('change', function() {
    imagesPreview(this, 'div.gallery');
});
});
```

Images I get from input file field in my view. And now I want append for each image another image like "delete". How can I do that?My div now is empty:

```
<div class="preview">

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply create the html needed and just use something like this:

```
$($.parseHTML('<div class="someClass">close</div>')).appendTo('.preview');
```

And then just listen for

```
$('.someClass').click(function(){
    // do stuff
});
```

Comment: but this code create element near image I appended before. I need to append some image "on" my previous appended image.

Comment: So you need to like print a cross on the image after its been printed to the screen?

Comment: I need to have like delete icon of each image. I can do this only for uploaded images. Maybe, I need just append img with some style? I was try to use position:relative and absolute of that images but it doesn't work.All image make one image in div.

Comment: Put in a code example, maybe use codepin, or pastebin or similar